# Wireless not Working BCM43142 Ubuntu 12.10 on Sony Vaio Fit 15E SVF15414CXB

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, broadcom, vaio

I recently bought Sony Vaio Fit 15E SVF15414CXB. 
It has a AMD 64-bit processor and is pre-installed with Windows 8.

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and made it dual boot.
But to my surprise no wireless network is detected on Ubuntu.
Even the option "Enable wireless" does not appear.

```
$ lshw -c network
product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
.
.
.
configuration : latency=0

$ iwconfig
eth0  no wireless extensions
lo    no wireless extensions

$ lspci -nn
02:00.0 Network Controller [0280] : Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I followed the following methods without success:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx --> this link does not say anything about BCM43142 chipset
2. tried with ndiswrapper following the procedure on Ubuntu documentation , but no luck.
3. http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2013/11/installing-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless.html --> no luck - but there is no file named wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb available on internet now (might be there previously), therefore this method failed.

So I'm unable to use wireless on my Ubuntu 12.10, however wired connection works.

Comment: I suggest you install Ubuntu 13.10 and then bcmwl-kernel-source.

Comment: thanks chili555..i applied your suggestion and now i have wifi in ubuntu 13.10